# How to get multiple results based on two different conditions from one table using single query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table which list number of sales for each day and the related sales amount. Following is the table SalesMaster.

```
Date     Item Sales Amount
30062018 1    5     50000
30062018 2    5     50000
30062018 3    5     50000
30062018 4    5     50000
30062018 5    5     50000
30062018 6    5     50000
30062018 7    5     50000
31052018 1    5     50000
31052018 2    5     50000
31052018 3    5     50000
31052018 4    5     50000
31052018 5    5     50000
31052018 6    5     50000
```

From this table I want to get the following result. I want to list the number of Sales for each item for each month end which is like below.

```
Item May_Sales June_Sales
1    5000      5000
2    5000      5000
3    5000      5000
4    5000      5000
5    5000      5000
6    5000      5000
7    5000      5000
```

Following is the code I wrote but it says, [1]: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row.

```
SELECT t1.item,
       sales AS may_sales,
       (SELECT sales
          FROM salesmaster t1
         WHERE t1.date = '30-June-2018')
           AS june_sales
  FROM salesmaster t1
 WHERE t1.date = '31-May-2018'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT sm.item,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t1.date = '31052018' then sales END) as may_sales,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t1.date = '30062018' then sales END) as june_sales
FROM salesmaster sm
GROUP BY sm.item
ORDER BY sm.item;
```

Your first column doesn't look like a date, so don't use date comparisons on it.  If it is a date, then use:

```
SELECT sm.item,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t1.date = DATE '2018-05-31' THEN sales END) as may_sales,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t1.date = DATE '2018-06-30' THEN sales END) as june_sales
FROM salesmaster sm
GROUP BY sm.item
ORDER BY sm.item;
```

As for your query, it is missing a correlation clause on `item` in the subquery.

EDIT:

If you want the difference, you need to repeat the expressions.  Here is one method:

```
SELECT sm.item,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t1.date = '31052018' THEN sales END) as may_sales,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t1.date = '30062018' THEN sales END) as june_sales,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t1.date = '31052018' THEN -sales) 
                WHEN t1.date = '30062018' THEN sales
           END) as diff,
```

Comment: Hi, if I want to get the difference of the two months as another column, I tried the following,
SUM (may_sales - june_sales) AS vriance. It doesn't give me a value and says [1]: ORA-00904: "JUNE_SALES": invalid identifier

Comment: Hi, I tried editing the calculation part only to get the positive values and constants value 0 for the negative ones.  I repeated the above conditions but I can only get the 0 for negative ones and I do not get anything for the rest. Any suggestion on this?.

Answer (score 0):

For the results you want to achieve, conditional aggregation will be the best approach:

```
select 
  item,  
  sum(case when to_date(Date, 'DDMMYYYY') between to_date('01052018','YYYYMMDD') and to_date('31052018','DDMMYYYY') then Amount else 0 end) may_sales, 
  sum(case when to_date(Date, 'DDMMYYYY') between to_date('01062018','YYYYMMDD') and to_date('31062018','DDMMYYYY') then Amount else 0 end) june_sales
from SalesMaster
group by item
order by item;
```

You have to convert your Date field into valid fields to get the monthly aggregates.

Answer (score 0):

```
select item, may.sales as MAY_sales, JUNE.sales as JUNE_sales  from
(SELECT distinct item
FROM salesmaster )MAST  
left join 
(SELECT item , sales
FROM salesmaster 
WHERE date = '31052018') MAY
on (MAST.item = JUNE.item)
left join 
(SELECT item , sales
FROM salesmaster 
WHERE date = '31052018') JUNE
on (MAST.item = JUNE.item)
```